# Find the absolute and relative error for a calculator with incorrect rounding

Tags: arithmetic, absolute-value, calculator, error-propagation

A calculator is out of order. The calculator will round up every single number to the nearest integer if the value at the first decimal digit is 6 and above, or else it rounds down the number to be nearest integer. Calculate the absolute and relative error for the solution if we use the calculators to perform the following calculations:

a) $\sqrt{6.8} - \sqrt{6.3}$

b)$\frac{5}{9}+\frac{2}{3}.\frac{3}{5}$

I tried to round up or down the figure individually and my answer for the absolute error in a) is $0.9023$, for relative error is $9.2354 $.

Comment: Anyone help?????????

Comment: i tried to round up or down the figure individually and my answer for the absolute error in a is 0.9023, for relative error is 9.2354

Answer (score 0):

[The answer explained by a youtuber I watched it a long time ago](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: Link-only answers aren't really all too welcome on Math SX. I'm sure this link is interesting and relevant, so perhaps you should turn it into a comment? Food for thought!

Comment: @MickG,absolutely right!!

Comment: BUT he only has 1 rep, so he can't really convert it…